# Joomla adding field

Tags: joomla-2.5, fix-my-code

I am pretty new to joomla.
Hope you guys can help me out with a simple problem.
I am trying to add a new field in this form
http://nanyangacademics.techiequickie.com/index.php/browsetutors
(you have to click on this)
[image]

Then a pop up opens, but unable to find where is this form and the fields, I would like to add a remarks field. TKs.

Answer (score 3):

The button on your site displays the URL http://nanyangacademics.techiequickie.com/index.php/processrequest as an Iframe in the modal window. You have to find out where *that* page is generated. It's probably a component, so look for any component with "form" in the name in your admin area under the "Components" menu.

If you disable SEF urls (in Global Configuration), the URL might show what component is used when visiting the site.